# Uploading Images for a section

Tags: images

I am looking for some help with a problem please.  I am building a site for a friend who is a travel writer. She has loads of images she has taken over the last few years.

Here is the question, we have over 4000 images which can be broken down into areas, but what I want to be able to do is upload the images to an area (category/taxonomy), so that when she goes on her travels again this year, she can upload images just to that section and when she does the post back at her hotel only see the images to that area in the Media upload / add media?

I have looked at a number of plugins but nothing seems to do it, and I really don't want to make changes to the core files of WordPress with the updates that are coming down the line this year.

Any thoughts would be helpful

Kind regards

John

Comment: Do you mean that the media chooser should filter images that are tagged with the specific taxonomy which is also used for the post she's writing? Or do you want those tagged images to automatically show up with the post when she writes and tags the post? Or something else?

Comment: Hi there J,  It would be nice if the media chooser could filter the images for her.  That would be great!  Any ideas, I am still looking all over the net for answers.  Cheers John.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Media Library Assistant plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/media-library-assistant/

I've never used it, but it looks like you can bulk-edit media files' taxonomies and filter them by whatever taxonomy you choose.

Comment: Hi there J,  Thank you for t5he feedback, I am going to look at the plugin now and I will report back to you soon.  Thank you for your input. Kind regards.